# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) angular4 typescript

Tags: database, angular

I am working with ANGULAR4. 
My issue here is to extract data from a database and show it on my interface. 
I am facing a problem: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Do anyone of you have an idea, please?

Comment: It literally says: "Not Found". The resource you are trying to fetch is not there. Your url might be wrong or it actually doesn't exist  in the database.

Comment: Maybe you've made a typo in the url?